# Workaround for blocking async?

Tags: c++, c++11

The `async` call below is blocking because the destructor of the returned future is blocking:

```
void foo() {}

void foo_async() {
    std::async(std::launch::async, foo);
}
```

But I don't want to block!

I'm considering to use the following workaround:

```
void foo_async() {
    std::thread(foo).detach();
}
```

Is this ok? Or would you recommend a different solution?

Comment: If you have no need to return a value from the task or to wait for it to finish this seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the following version of async which provides a non-blocking future. As such you can take advantage of the future if you need it and on the other side you can just ignore it when you want a fire-and-forget task.

```
template< class Function, class... Args>
std::future<typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type> async( Function&& f, Args&&... args ) 
{
    typedef typename std::result_of<Function(Args...)>::type R;
    auto bound_task = std::bind(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::packaged_task<R()> task(std::move(bound_task));
    auto ret = task.get_future();
    std::thread t(std::move(task));
    t.detach();
    return ret;   
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is non-blocking? To me, it  seems like it would still block on the other side once the future destructor is called.

Comment: @thejinx0r future destructor from packaged task doesn't block

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to fire-and-forget the call to `foo()`, I would say your workaround is OK.

Otherwise, just do `auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, foo);`, and possibly return the future from `foo_async()`.

Comment: If an exception escapes from `foo`, boom.

Comment: @LucDanton That's true with `std::async`, but at least you can catch it when you `get()` on `f`. With the `std::thread` approach it's unrecoverable.