# how can i test synchronize function in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++11, synchronization

i have a synchronize function that i want to test if it ends.
i want to be able to run code for X time, and if the time ends to continue.
here what i want:

```
bool flag = false;
some_function_that_run_the_next_block_for_x_sec()
{
   my_sync_func_that_i_want_to_test();
   flag = true;
}
Assert::IsTrue(flag);
```

is there a simple way to do this?

[SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you posted gives me little insight on how that class would be used (maybe Microsoft is saving up bytes on sample code to pay for Ballmer's golden parachute next year?) so pardon me for completely ignoring it.

Something like this:

```
auto result = async(launch::async, my_sync_func_that_i_want_to_test);
future_status status = result.wait_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
if (status == future_status::timeout)
    cout << "Timed out" << endl;
if (status == future_status::ready)
    cout << "Finished on time" << endl;
```

Need inclusion of the `<future>` and `<chrono>` headers.

If `my_sync_func_that_i_want_to_test()` never finishes you'll have another problem. The `future` object (`result`) will block until the thread launched by `async()` finishes. There's no portable way to recover from "killed/canceled/aborted" threads, so this will probably require some platform-specific code, even if you roll out your own `async_that_detaches_the_thread()` (which is not hard to find, [here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296284/workaround-for-blocking-async)).